# Are there any notable differences between calling an event handling using 'Invoke' and using a 'traditional method call'?

Tags: c#, event-handling

An event handler can be invoked by either of the following:

```
SomeEventHandler.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

or

```
SomeEventHandler(this, new EventArgs());
```

Are there any notable differences between the two versions? Perhaps in terms of performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same. They will be compiled to the same code. The difference with the two is that the `Invoke` method allows you (in C# 6) to use the null-conditional operator `?.` to check if the handler is initialized before you invoke it. In the first case, you have to do the following

```
if (SomeEventHandler != null)
    SomeEventHandler(this, new EventArs());
```

whereas with `Invoke` you can do

```
SomeEventHandler?.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
```

I hope this helps.